# Cannot Keep Ajax Preserved Session Variables

Tags: php, ajax, session-variables

I am trying to write code to bring session variables from one php to another without refreshing. I tried to follow the example I found on web as below. It seems to bring the value successfully when loading the ajax page. However, the session variable created seems unable to be preserved even I use the `session_start()` command. Instead of loading the data, it shows the following error message:

> Notice: Undefined index: numSum in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\update.php on line 5

I'd appreciate it if anyone can advise what to do with the code in order to get it right.

**index.php**

```
<html>
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    j_TOC = [1,2,3,4,5];

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "update.php",
      data: { numSum: j_TOC}
    })

      .done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      });

 </script>
</html>
```

**update.php**

```
<html>
<?php
    session_start();
    session_save_path('/session_data/');
    $_SESSION['numSum1'] = $_POST['numSum'];

    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function atest() {

        var id_toc = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['numSum1']); ?>;
        window.alert(id_toc);
    {

</script>
    <input type="button" id="clickme" onclick="atest()" value="update session"></>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your code, such as:

- **Normal code flow:** When you first visit *index.php*, it will trigger the AJAX request, and will subsequently set the session variable; so that when you visit *update.php* page, you'll get the desired result.
- **Your code flow:** Having said the above point, if you directly visit the *update.php* page without visiting *index.php* in the first place, you'll get this error,

  > Notice: Undefined index: numSum in ...

  And that's because `$_POST['numSum']` is not set, in fact, the entire superglobal `$_POST` array is empty.

  So **the solution** is this,

  Wrap this statement `$_SESSION['numSum1'] = $_POST['numSum'];` inside an `if` block, like this:

  ```
  if(!isset($_SESSION['numSum1']) || empty($_SESSION['numSum1'])){
      $_SESSION['numSum1'] = isset($_POST['numSum']) ? $_POST['numSum'] : array();
  }
  ```
- There's also a small syntax error in your code,

  ```
  function atest() {

      var id_toc = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['numSum1']); ?>;
      window.alert(id_toc);
  {   <============ See here, it should be }
  ```

  You forgot to add a closing parentheses `}`
- Finally, from [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php#Parameters),

  > ... Session data path. If specified, the path to which data is saved will be changed. **`session_save_path()` needs to be called before `session_start()` for that purpose.**

#### Edited:

Change your `if` block in the following way,

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['numSum1']) || empty($_SESSION['numSum1']) || (isset($_POST['numSum']) && $_POST['numSum'] != $_SESSION['numSum1'])){
    $_SESSION['numSum1'] = isset($_POST['numSum']) ? $_POST['numSum'] : array();
}
```

Also, learn about comparison operators in PHP, especially about ternary operator. The question mark(`?:`) you're talking about is related to ternary operator. Here are the necessary references,

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php (Comparison operators)
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary (Ternary operator)

Comment: Many thanks for the solution. It words to some extent. I now can get the session variable data on the update.php. However, it cannot be changed. Specifically. when I change the j_TOC to 2,2,3,4,5, for example in the index.php and reload the index.php, the update.php still gives me 1,2,3,4,5. Is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: Also, could you explain a little bit more about the syntax you provided, as I am new to php. Specifically, what is the meaning of "?" in the middle of the statement "$_SESSION['numSum1'] = isset($_POST['numSum']) ? $_POST['numSum'] : array();"? And what is the meaning of "$_POST['numSum'] : array()"? Finally, i see your whole statement seems to be checking whether the session variable is empty or exists, and never see you assign the $_POST value to the session variable, which statement take up this work actually? Many thanks!

Comment: @CL.L I've updated my answer, please see the **Edited** section of my answer.

Comment: Got with many thanks, now I understand the ternary operator. Could I have a followup question? I understand your code which is effective but only after the update.php is refreshed. However, could we update the value without refreshing the page update.php, instead just click on "update session" button? Or we have to refresh the page to run the php part in order to get it work?

Comment: @CL.L Session variable can only be updated through *index.php* page because that's where you're passing new value, rather array. If you click on *update session* button, it will only show you whatever is there in `$_SESSION['numSum1']`, that's it. If you want to update the session on *update.php* page, by clicking *update session* button, make a `form` containing a new session value and this *update session* button, and during form processing, update `$_SESSION['numSum1']`.

Comment: Ok, I see. So we have to use form submitting to do this. I will try. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`session_save_path()` should be called prior to `session_start()`, and if you're going to use it, use it both scripts where you use `session_start()`

`update.php` should just return a string for `alert()`. When you load that page directly, `$_POST` is empty, so that is the error you're seeing.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. So can it do without setting session path? And could you show me how to refine the code so that I can pass the value between pages?

Comment: I am trying to do the posting issue with this code:  if ($_SESSION['numSum1']=="") {
  $_SESSION['numSum1'] = $_POST['numSum'];
  } else {
  echo $_SESSION['numSum1'];
 }